# How to safely use the .substring method in a linq where clause

Tags: .net, linq

I have two datetime pickers that I'm using to set a start and end date for desired records in a database. The "dates" in the database are stored as strings in the format `yyyymmdd`, but some dates are missing characters (ex. 2001094, which is missing the last digit on the day).

I want to write a single LINQ query that pulls the records for the relevant timespan, but if I just do this:

```
var = 
    from rec in datacontext 
    where rec.date.substring(0,8) is in the daterange 
    select rec
```

then I get out of range exceptions for the short stringed records (because they are not 8 characters long).

Right now I'm pulling in the whole table and using two lambdas to (1) remove all the records that don't begin with 8 integers and then (2) remove all of the now .substring-safe records that don't match the range. This works, but it's really ugly.

If I have two conditions in my where clause, does LINQ evaluate them sequentially? So if I say

```
from ... where (rec.date starts with 8 integers) AND (rec.date is in range)
```

will LINQ skip over records when it sees they don't match the first condition?

The only other thing I can think of (also sort of ugly) is to use `.StartsWith` instead of `.SubString` in the initial LINQ queries, and then use lambdas after the initial query to remove the out of range records. This is better than pulling in all rows like I'm doing now, but not really the elegant single query I'm looking for.

```
if datetimepickers are both in the same year...
var=from ... where rec.date.startswith(yyyy) 'at least I'm not pulling in everything...
var.remove(lambda to remove short date strings)
var.remove(lambda to remove out of range dates)
```

Comment: This is screaming to use `DateTime.TryParse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, adding a check for the lenght of the string will fix the problem. In this case, LINQ will evaluate the first part of an AND condition and then stop evaluating if it fails. So if it has A && B, if A is false, then it won't evaluate B

```
var=from rec in datacontext where rec.date.length >= 8 && rec.date.substring(0,8) is in the daterange select rec
```

Comment: That is the crux of my question. Will LINQ skip over records when they don't match the first condition of a multi-condition where clause?

Comment: In my expereience the answer is yes, however I doubt that it is guaranteed to be the case, as linq is functional, it can choose to evaluate however it wants. I believe the LINQ provider is what determines this ordering.

Comment: If you wanted to force evaluation order, or guarantee its ordering I would recommend making an extension method so that you can call rec.date.myextensionMethod()

Comment: Your answer seems to be right. LINQ stops evaluating once it fails the first condition. Does anyone know if that is a general rule for how LINQ works?

Comment: It is determined by the Linqprovider. Its not specific to all linq. It could change in linq to sql as compared to linq to objects for example. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx

Comment: Thanks again. As far as you know, LINQ to SQL evaluates the first condition? Also, at first I tried to implement your extension method suggestion and I got all kinds of errors. It seems like you need to put a predicate in the LINQ where clause: http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/09/05/Calling+Custom+Methods+In+LINQtoSQL.aspx If you just put a boolean method in the where clause LINQ won't know how to 'reach into' that code and translate it to see the logic/translate it to T-SQL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6444/discussion-between-dessus-and-akh2103)